# Is there any way to clear dbms_output in sql developer before each execution?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was searching for this solution so long.

This is kind of frustrating and feels stupid to clear dbms_output manually before each execution to see the results for latest run.

Is there any way to clear dbms_output before each run.

"clear screen" only clears script output.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so. I often output a header at the top of my script in these cases just to keep the runs separate, like `dbms_output.put_line('---- ' || sysdate || '----');`

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, not.

Jeff Smith said so, here: https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/03/dbms_output-in-sql-developer/ (search for "clear"). He suggests using Script Output panel instead, but that's what you already know.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, sort of using script output now as there is no way around.